# Iterating through a multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following Array which is stored in $_SESSION I wish to itterate through and display the values in the format stated below the array:

```
    Array
(
[step_one] => Array
    (
        [width-ft] => 2
        [width-in] => 0
        [height-ft] => 2
        [height-in] => 0
    )

[step_two] => Array
    (
        [range] => penshaw
    )

[step_three] => Array
    (
        [style] => arch
    )

[step_four] => Array
    (
        [detail] => double bow
    )

[step_five] => Array
    (
        [decor] => circle
    )

[step_six] => Array
    (
        [basket] => round collar
    )

[step_seven] => Array
    (
        [finial] => spear
    )

)
```

Now How to iterate out the values like so:

```
 width-ft: 2
 width-in: 0
 height-ft: 2
 height-in: 0

 range: penshaw
 style: arch
 detail: double bow
 decor: circle
 basket: round collar
 finial: spear
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider reading up on how to work with Arrays in PHP rather than asking for a concrete solution to such a basic problem. 
It will help you improve your skills and save time.
https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+iterate+over+an+array+php

Comment: sometimes in life you need a quick solution, thanks for the google query...

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting Daans Answer so this Question will get no further, unneeded attention and also, Daan will get some reputation points and so will you. A win-win one might say :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
foreach($array as $stepArray) {
  foreach($stepArray as $key => $value) {
       echo $key.": ".$value;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the variable $stepArray doing here? It works, so thanks just not sure how.

Comment: $stepArray means all of the arrays inside the top array for example: [step_one] => Array

Comment: @Rik89 Once again, consider actually reading something about the topic you are working on. http://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: If this did helped you, you might wanna at least upvote, or do right thing which is accepting this as an answer.